# How to add a custom PMD rule in Jenkins PMD plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pmd, rule

I want to use a custom rule in PMD.
I installed the PMD-plugin in jenkins, I also created a jar with :

1. A ruleset file
2. The java code for the custom rule (the custom rule extends from AbstractJavaRule).

I added this jar in the lib directory of the PMD plugin (jenkins/plugins/pmd/WEB-INF/lib).

I also added this in the pom.xml of a project (to test PMD):

```
        <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                     <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                        <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                        <rulesets>
                                 <ruleset>/rulesets/basic.xml</ruleset>
                        </rulesets>                  
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

How can I tell to the jenkins PMD-plugin to use my new JAVA rule ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the first step is, to get the custom PMD rule working without Jenkins.
Jenkins will trigger the maven build, which will trigger PMD to create the report file `pmd.xml` and then the Jenkins PMD plugin will parse this `pmd.xml` file.

1. Maven - you've added the maven-pmd-plugin in the reporting section. This means, you'll need to generate the site, in order to get the PMD reports (run `mvn site`. It is also possible to run PMD during the build, e.g. run the `pmd:pmd` in phase `verify`. See also [PMD Mojo Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/pmd-mojo.html).
2. In order to have your custom rule and custom ruleset available, you'll need to add your jar as an additional dependency to the maven-pmd-plugin section, e.g.

   ```
   ...
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.7.1</version>
       ...
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.your.custom.rule</groupId>
               <artifactId>custom-rule</artifactId>
               <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. Verify, that a `mvn site` will generate the pmd report, usually under `target/pmd.xml`.
4. It might be, that the Jenkins PMD plugin now just shows your rule, but without the documentation like code examples and description. This is implemented in the [PMDMessages](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pmd-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/pmd/parser/PmdMessages.java) class and uses "RegisteredRuleSets" feature of PMD, which is not good documented, but the sourcecode is [here](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/pmd/4.3.x/pmd/src/net/sourceforge/pmd/RuleSetFactory.java#L48) (for PMD 4.3).
5. Add a properties file named `rulesets.properties` in the directory `rulesets` in your jar. You would place this file in the source tree usually under `src/main/resources/rulesets/rulesets.properties`. The file needs to have the following content

   ```
   rulesets.filenames=rulesets/custom-ruleset-1.xml,rulesets/custom-ruleset-2.xml
   ```

It contains a comma-separated list of ruleset files. If you add this file in your jar, then the Jenkins PMD Report should contain the info you want.

Please note, that there is already a newer version of the Maven PMD Plugin available, currently the latest version is 3.5. This version is based on PMD 5 which introduced multiple languages and the path to the rulesets.properties file changes to `rulesets/java/rulesets.properties` in case of java.